# Detecting State Change for a variable

Tags: go

I am writing a code to detect state change based on a threshold value. Main goal is to get a return value from the function only when the state changes. Here is the code I have written so far. If the state of variable does not change currently we are returning `""` empty string in the return value of the function. Is there a way that we can suppress the return value if the state does not changes, instead of returning `""` (empty string)

`

```
func (f *stateChange) Exec(args []interface{}, _ api.FunctionContext) (interface{}, bool) {
    
    m1 := args[0]
    m2 := m1.([]interface{})
    valarray := []float64{}
    
    for _, v := range m2 {
        valarray = append(valarray, v.(float64))
    }
    
    
    firstval := valarray[0]
    secondval := valarray[1]
    
    message1 := "Medium Level Alarm"
    message2 := "High Level Alarm"
    message3 := "Normal Operation"

    message4 := ""  //**empty string**
    
    if secondval >= 50 && secondval < 100 && firstval < 50{
    
    return message1, true
    }
    if firstval >= 100 && secondval < 100 && secondval >= 50{
    
    return message1, true
    }   
    
    if secondval >= 100 && firstval < 100{
    
    return message2, true   
    }   

    if firstval >= 50 && secondval < 50 {
    
    return message3, true
    
    }
    
    return message4, true //**empty string in return need to suppress this output**
    

}
```

`

Comment: `return nil, true` works

Answer (score 1):

The best way to suppress this output is using `nil`.

```
return nil, true
```